# Jquery Validation for input fields

Tags: jquery

I need to set a jquery validation for my name field in such a way that it allows the user to enter only alphanumeric characters that is combination of letters and numbers but no need to enter numbers only.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far and what issues have you encountered?

Comment: We don't have your code. How do you expect us to help ??

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions. I use https://jqueryvalidation.org/ validation plugin, and just in case you're using the same plugin, here you have a simple custom method (pretty sure I got it from stackoverflow.com/a/5732255/5437621)...

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value,element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(value);
}, "This field can only have letters and numbers.");
```

... but anyway, what is important for you here is this...

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(yourInputValue);
```

... this will tell you if the value has only letters and numbers.

**IMPORTANT: I've been using this alphanumeric function for a long time, and pasted it directly from one of my applications, but as @mrid comments, I probably got it from this (stackoverflow.com/a/5732255/5437621) or another answer (honestly, I don't remember it but is probably like that). Sorry, I didn't want to appropiate from other's work.**

I hope it helps

Comment: Why using a library for a simple validation ?

Comment: No, no... I just put the whole function just in case he's using the same plugin. That's why I continue extracting the regular expression test. I'll edit the answer to clarify

Comment: calm down bud, I was just informing you, i'll take down my comment

Comment: You're completely right! I've edited the question (apologize included).

Comment: @mrid Wov, thanks, man! And please, leave the comment. I really like you notice and advice me of that. I use this so much that sometimes is hard to remember what I've done or what I've gotten from here! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses https://jqueryvalidation.org/ :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#inp").keyup(function(e) {
  var str = $.trim($(this).val());
  if (str != "") {
    var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    if (!regx.test(str)) {
      $("#error").html("alphanumeric only");
    } else {
      if (isNaN(str))
        $("#error").html('');
      else
        $("#error").html("alphanumeric only");
    }
  } else {

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" type="text">


<span id="error"></span>
```

Comment: @Anitha you can upvote this and mark it as an answer if it helped :)